# mysql query to show what doesnt match

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL queries.

The first shows what training has been done by a person. The second shows what training is required for a job.

**First query**

```
select training from coursescompleted where person='$person'
```

**Second query**

```
select j.job, r.training from riskstraining r join jobsrisks j on j.risk=r.Risk
```

As an example, the output of the first query (training completed) is:

```
first aid course
Firesystems course
```

And the output of the second query (training needed) is:

```
Security Guard   -   Firesystems Course
Crane Operator   -   Driving LicenseCourse
Crane Operator   -   first aid course
```

How do I combine these queries to show what courses are required in order to do a job? As per the example below, if I chose the job 'crane operator', the result should be 'Driving License Course' as the person has already completed the 'first aid course'. A join will show the results where they match, not where they don't match.

**Desired output** - where 'crane operator' is chosen

```
crane operator   -   driving license course
```

Any advice or guidance on what the query should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select j.job, r.training from riskstraining r join jobsrisks j on j.risk=r.Risk
where r.training not in 
(select training from coursescompleted where person='$person')
```

something like that I guess.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks to you, I learnt an another solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The following will do the trick:

```
select j.job, r.training 
from riskstraining r join jobsrisks j on j.risk=r.Risk
left join 
(select training from coursescompleted  where person='$person') cc 
on r.training = cc.training 
WHERE cc.training IS NULL
```

You can check a simulation for the code [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8abf/18)

Comment: Thanks a million, your updated code is also working 100%. is any solution more preferrable if your answer is compared to @zato which also works?